# How to sort an array of objects by the value of a field using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Given the following:

```
var array = [{"name":"zoe", "hotdogs":5},{"name":"april", "hotdogs":5},{"name":"ryan", "hot dogs":8}]
```

How can I sort the elements of the array by name using JavaScript?

```
var array = [{"name":"april", "hotdogs":5},{"name":"ryan", "hotdogs":8},{"name":"zoe", "hotdogs":5}]
```

Is there a way to apply some function to sort the objects? Are there helper libraries that help with performance?

I tried the following:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.name > b.name
});
```

But it appeared to have no effect on the resulting array when I try to print it out whatsoever.

Comment: Try `return (a.name>b.name)-(b.name>a.name)`. `.sort` interprets `0` (AKA `+false`) as "equals"

Comment: @JanDvorak is correct http://jsfiddle.net/avWXu/

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how this is a duplicate of the other. The other's accepted answer shows using `parseFloat`. No details are given that the sort function must return -1, 0, 1 so the answers on the other question are basically irrelevant to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.localeCompare()`.

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
});
```

- [MDN `.localeCompare()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: This is horrible answer. From the docs you linked to: *the locale and sort order used are entirely implementation dependent*. Great. So I get one sort on the server, and different sort on every user's machine. No thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function should return integer, like C strcmp, so do:

```
if a.name > b.name {
  return 1;
} else if ( a.name == b.name) {
  return 0;
}
return -1
```

Comment: `"zoe"-"april" => NaN`